# How can i know if someone in the network connected to the SQL Express 2008 on my system

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-express

I have installed a SQL Express 2008 Server on my Desktop for some local work. This has mixed authentication. I have enabled TCP/IP connection so that one colleague can connect to this server. However, this exposes the server to everyone in the network. How do i keep track of which PC in the network connected to this server and when ? This would just help me audit the usage of the server.

Comment: Is your local network a part of a domain? If it is, you could only give access to your colleague using his domain account (windows authentication).

Answer (score 0):

Well you can get information about current users, sessions, and processes in an instance by using

```
sp_who;
```

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174313.aspx)

Comment: I can choose to view 'Top Connections' from the 'Reports' option of the server. This shows all the clients who connected since last session. However, i wanted to know if there was a continuous log not just from last session. Or a way to be alerted.